# How to print in Printer's Default fonts using C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, non-ascii-characters, dot-matrix

i have LQ EPSON 300 Printer

i want to Print some data in Printer's default font

i think it will be possible if we use c# code to print by that printer's default font.

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 950, 555);
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.FontAndLocation);
pd.Print();

private void FontAndLocation(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox1.Text.ToString(), new Font("Bookman Old Style", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 20, 95);
   e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox2.Text.ToString(), new Font("Bookman Old Style", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 20, 165);
   e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox3.Text.ToString(), new Font("Courier New", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 20, 265);
}
```

i try to search through Internet but i failed, i could not fix my problem yet 
The code that i write do not printing in Draft/dot-matrix(Printer's Default)  Fonts.
can we call printer in code or any code that make it possible to print in EPSON-LQ 300 default font?

Comment: I want to print text in text-boxes in draft font which the default font of the my printer

Comment: What's the name of that default font?  What driver is in use (Epson/Ms)? You're at the mercy of that driver maybe recognizing a font as installed.

Comment: i just want to print the Courier New and Bookman Old Style font text in Dot-Matrix font, it will possible if we write code for print the data through printer's default font

Comment: You didn't answer my question: what names does the printer use for its fonts?

Comment: And what is wrong with the current output?

Comment: You cannot use PrintDocument, you have to send the print commands directly to the printer, bypassing the printer driver.  The only way to get fast output from a dot-matrix printer like that.  Covered by [this KB article](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/322091).

Comment: the printer is : EPSON-LQ 300

Comment: and the the font of that printer is draft

Comment: i want to use printer's default fonts which is  draft font bcz then it will print fast with using less ink